# How to use ngAfterChanges in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

[`ngOnChanges`](https://pub.dev/documentation/angular/latest/angular/OnChanges/ngOnChanges.html) is deprecated in favour of [`ngAfterChanges`](https://pub.dev/documentation/angular/latest/angular/AfterChanges/ngAfterChanges.html), but the former was given a list of properties that changed. The latter gets nothing. How do I know what changed so I can only perform expensive actions if a particular `@Input` changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the list of changes was actually expensive itself. So it was dropped instead I would suggest having a setter mark if something has changed for just the expensive inputs.